# Xcode/Git: Can't see old version in source control

Tags: xcode, git

I've just followed a basic tutorial on how to use Git in Xcode. I've made a new project with Git initialised from when I created it. I then made some changes and after hitting commit, instead of getting the old and the new files side by side I'm seeing nothing on the right hand side, just says 'File is unversioned'. I definitely have Git turned on - I got the Modified tag for example as I made changes to a couple of files.
Any ideas why this is so?[image]

Comment: Does this happen for *every* file in the project? The file in question might not be tracked by git by default.

Comment: Was there a commit *before* the edit? If not this is the only tracked version of the file.

Comment: @esqew: that was it, I thought it opened on the file most recently modified as it was open on the project folder, but on another file. Thanks a lot. trojanfoe, I thought Xcode always does that first initial commit for you as soon as you create a new project, so I would expect there to always be one to compare to? Am I wrong about this or did I miss what you meant? I edited files and then did a single commit. It worked but I was on the wrong file.